# Custom height of the navbar in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to set a custom height to my navbar. The code that i have works fine in iOS 11, Xcode 8; but now, i have Xcode 9 and iOS 11 and the code is not working. This is what i have...

```
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height:82) 
    view.addSubview(navBar)
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.view.frame.width, height: 82)
}
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: so you have two navigation bars??

Comment: sorry... i updated the changes

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (bounds?.width)!, height: (bounds?.height)! + height)
```

Comment: i tried, but the navbar doesn't changes the height yet

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!!

I searched and i found an example in the Apple Documentation. I simply did this:

-I created a class of type UIView and i putted this:

```
class ExtendedNavBarView: UIView {

override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
    super.willMove(toWindow: newWindow)

    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat(1) / UIScreen.main.scale)
    layer.shadowRadius = 0

    layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
}
```

}

-Then, i putted this in viewDidLoad:

```
    navBar.shadowImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TransparentPixel")

    let extendedBar = ExtendedNavBarView()
    extendedBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 82)
    view.addSubview(extendedBar)

    extendedBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 249/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1.0)

    self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 82)
    view.addSubview(navBar)
```